# can we list all tables in msaccess database using sql?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Can we find all tables in the msaccess using sql .

as we do in sqlserver

```
select * from sys.tables
```

in sqlite

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master where type='table'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [MSysObjects](http://www.perfectparadigm.com/tip001.html)

```
SELECT * FROM MSysObjects WHERE Type=1 AND Flags=0
```

Comment: That throws this error: `OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TEST" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'.".` I mapped `sa` to `Admin`. What is required to get the results?

Comment: Just found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cd6eadd-2d9d-4dbd-8920-e2847a74f80a/retrieve-all-msaccess-table-names-using-openrowset-funtion-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql "Because MSysObjects is a system table in Access, the Admin user does not have permission to read data in it."

Answer (score 4):

Ms Access has several system tables that are, by default, hidden from tables list. You can show them.

In Ms Access 2007 do a right click on tables list and select `Navigation Options`. At the bottom of the form you will find `Show System Objects` check box. Check it and system tables will show up in tables list. They all start with `MSys`.
Alternatively, options form can be activated from application menu - click button `Access options` -> select `Current Database` and there is `Navigation Options` button.

Now you can examine structure and contents and generate queries of all system tables with MsAccess tools.

As Alex answered, table information is in `MSysObjects`

Answer (score 3):

The following query helped me scope a redesign/migration from MS Access to C# & SQL Server.

Note: Combines answers provided by both [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k) and [KTys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870687/ktys). 

Posted here with the belief that it will be useful to someone else (or myself if I have to do this again)

```
SELECT
  SWITCH (
    [type]=-32764,'Report' ,
    [type]  =  1, 'Table, local' ,
    [type]  =  3, 'obj Containers' ,
    [type]  =  4, 'Table, link odbc' ,
    [type]  =  5, 'Query' ,
    [type]  =  6, 'Table, link access' ,
    [type]  =  8, 'SubDataSheets' ,
    TRUE, [type]
  ) AS [type name (or #)]
  , name AS [Table Name]
FROM
  MSysObjects 
ORDER BY 
  2, 3
```

Note warning from KTys (type numbers are subject to change)

Add `, *` to the select clause to see the other fields (such as connect); they weren't helpful to me.

Created/tested with MS Access 2013

Answer (score 1):

For Access 2013, I've used

SELECT name FROM MSysObjects WHERE type = 4

Answer (score 0):

**[This discussion gives](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?p=473720&postcount=3)** a list of Type values. Be aware that MS does not guarantee same values from version to version.

```
Type    TypeDesc
-32768  Form
-32766  Macro
-32764  Reports
-32761  Module
-32758  Users
-32757  Database Document
-32756  Data Access Pages
1   Table - Local Access Tables
2   Access Object - Database
3   Access Object - Containers
4   Table - Linked ODBC Tables
5   Queries
6   Table - Linked Access Tables
8   SubDataSheets
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM MSysObjects where database <> ''
```

use this query to get the names of all the linked tables